# Variable profit knapsack

Tags: ds.algorithms, dynamic-programming

sorry for bad formatting earlier

We are given Cx,i, Cy,i, Cz,i ∈ ℕ and Px,i, Py,i, Pz,i > 0 for i=1,2,3 such that Px,1 < Px,2 < Px,3, Py,1 < Py,2 < Py,3, and Pz,1 < Pz,2 < Pz,3. We are also given K∈ℕ.

The values Cx,i and Px,i describe the content of a stack named x. From top to bottom, the stack x contains Cx,1 items each of profit Px,1, Cx,2 items each of profit Px,2, and Cx,3 items each of profit Px,3. The contents of stacks y and z are defined in the same way.

We are allowed to pop K items in total from the three stacks. How can I maximize the total profit?

Comment: ok, what is your question?

Comment: it would be more readable if you used latex

Comment: And in general, it would be good to try to improve the formatting of the question. Now some parts are shown in a huge font (because they are marked as headings).

Comment: is this even within scope ?

Comment: Seriously, posters should put more effort into communicating their question. As of now I can't even tell what the question is about. Voted to close.

Comment: ditto. definitely vote to close. waiting for some more votes.

Comment: @Robin: I agree that askers should put an effort into communicating their questions, but is it that difficult to guess what this particular question is?  I am not saying that leaving the real question to a guess of reader is _good_, but it is definitely _possible_ to guess what the question here is.

Comment: The OP should email me if they wish to reopen the question after making the edits that Tsuyoshi suggests.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but the description of a problem which I think the asker wants to ask.

To vaibhav: While I believe that this is at least close to what you want to ask, please edit the question so that it is clearly understandable.  Otherwise, we can only make a guess about what is being asked.

We are given *C*<sub>x,*i*</sub>, *C*<sub>y,*i*</sub>, *C*<sub>z,*i*</sub> ∈ ℕ and *P*<sub>x,*i*</sub>, *P*<sub>y,*i*</sub>, *P*<sub>z,*i*</sub> > 0 for *i*=1,2,3 such that *P*<sub>x,1</sub> < *P*<sub>x,2</sub> < *P*<sub>x,3</sub>, *P*<sub>y,1</sub> < *P*<sub>y,2</sub> < *P*<sub>y,3</sub>, and *P*<sub>z,1</sub> < *P*<sub>z,2</sub> < *P*<sub>z,3</sub>.  We are also given *K*∈ℕ.

The values *C*<sub>x,*i*</sub> and *P*<sub>x,*i*</sub> describe the content of a stack named x.  From top to bottom, the stack x contains *C*<sub>x,1</sub> items each of profit *P*<sub>x,1</sub>, *C*<sub>x,2</sub> items each of profit *P*<sub>x,2</sub>, and *C*<sub>x,3</sub> items each of profit *P*<sub>x,3</sub>.  The contents of stacks y and z are defined in the same way.

We are allowed to retrieve *K* items in total from the three stacks.  How can we find efficiently the way to maximize the total profit?

Comment: Tsuyoshi, thanks you have explained it correctly. I am not sure why is was so hard for other to understand. How do I reopen the topic now? should I post your version of question to a new thread ?

Comment: And what does "efficiently" mean?

Comment: What I mean is: Since there are only 3 stacks, we can reduce the problem to consider 3^3=9 instances of having just one price of each "stack". That is we need only to solve 9 instances of the problem max p_x*x + p_y*y + p_z*z s.t. x+y+z <= B, x<=c_x, y<=c_y, z<=c_z.

Comment: @Kristoffer: I almost agree with you, but I definitely disagree about your claim that 3^3=9.  :)

Comment: @vaibhav: Please read [this FAQ entry](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/361#361) and others’ comments to understand why the question was closed.  It seems that the recommended action is to edit the question instead of reposting a new version.  After editing the question (and [rereading it](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/328#328)), email Suresh to ask him to reopen the quesiton.  (more)

Comment: @vaibhav: (cont’d)  However, before trying to improve the question, consider about Kristoffer Arnsfelt Hansen’s comments asking the meaning of “efficiently.”  I used the ambiguous word “efficiently” exactly because I did not know what kind of efficiency you are looking for.  In fact, I hope that considering about his comments may allow you to solve the problem by yourself.  (more)

Comment: @vaibhav: (cont’d)  Although this question was understandable to me, I have to say for the future that it was poorly written.  Please learn how to state a problem clearly.  Also, its bad formatting (unintended big letters) alone suggested that you did not care much about the question.  If you care about the question, please take time to make the question better.

Comment: @vaibhav: I forgot to say: If you ask for reopening, you should unmark the “accepted” mark of this answer, because you will want another answer.

Comment: Oops. I was thinking one thing and writing something else ;)

Comment: I have updated the problem.

Comment: @vaibhav: Did you email Suresh as he wrote?  I guess you can reach him by flagging the question for moderator attention and explaining the situation briefly in the flagging comment.  However, you almost copied my post (removing formatting) and simply removed the word “efficiently.”  Is that really what you want?  If you do not care about the efficiency, you can use brute-force search for almost anything.  Therefore, I would not ask moderators to reopen the question in the current form.

Comment: @vaibhav: For more about asking what you really want to ask, read [this FAQ entry](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/307#307) and [this FAQ entry](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/329#329).